# How can I access the current __FILE__ in a subclass from a method in the superclass in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

I'm hoping to set up a default path for logging, relative to the path of the file using the log, something like this:

```
# /path/to/lib/bar.rb
class Bar
  def settings_file_path
    File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))
  end
end

# /path/to/app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < Bar
end

Foo.new.settings_file_path
```

Ideal output:

```
# => /path/to/app/models
```

Actual output:

```
# => /path/to/lib
```

Because **FILE** references the file where it's written, not where it's being called from, it's returning the bar.rb file, but I want something like this to return the path of the foo.rb file, even though the method is defined in Bar.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest would be something like this:

```
# foo.rb
class Foo
  def self.my_file
    @my_file
  end
end

# bar.rb
class Bar < Foo
  @my_file = __FILE__
end

# main.rb
require_relative 'foo'
require_relative 'bar'
p Bar.my_file
#=> "/Users/phrogz/Desktop/bar.rb"
```

However, you could parse the caller in a self.inherited hook like so:

```
# foo.rb
class Foo
  class << self
    attr_accessor :_file
  end
  def self.inherited( k )
    k._file = caller.first[/^[^:]+/]
  end
end

# bar.rb
class Bar < Foo
end

# main.rb
require_relative 'foo'
require_relative 'bar'

p Bar._file
#=> "/Users/phrogz/Desktop/bar.rb"
```

I'm not certain how robust or portable that parsing is; I suggest you test it.

*N.B. My `Bar` inherits from `Foo`, the reverse of your question. Be not confused by the differences in our setups.*

Answer (score 1):

`caller.first[/^[^:]+/]` will not work on Windows because absolute path there looks like `$DRIVE:$PATH` (example `C:/Windows/system32`)

Instead `caller.first[/^[^:]+/]` use `caller_locations.first.absolute_path`

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 2.7 adds Module#const_source_location

```
const_source_location(:Foo)
```

Answer (score -3):

Use **$0** instead of __ FILE__ :)

Comment: This helps for sure, and was great to learn, but I guess my question was oversimplified. $0 returns the filename of the main program running, which works for my example, but not if I'm running a different file (or a whole Ruby on Rails app for example) which includes the Foo and Bar files. Thanks though!